# How to show custom Google Map in iPhone app using MapKit?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mapkit

Is there any way to show my custom Google map ("My maps" feature in Google Maps) in my iPhone App (MapKit)?

I know I can do some things with the maps using MKAnnotation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651847/google-maps-shading-ios), but I would like to create and edit custom map online (through Google Maps) and then display it on Google Maps (my personal map, associated with specified Google Account) on iPhone/iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not aware of anyway you can access your 'My Maps' from within MapKit. One option would be to use [Route Me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) which is an open source map view for iOS. Its fairly well developed now and straight forward to implement. I'm not sure specifically how you would use your maps, but changing a few URLs here and there in the code should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

At that point, if you're rendering google maps, you should abandon MapKit and use the Google Maps iOS SDK (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start)

I'm not sure from there's a native binding in there to access 'My Maps'.

I recommend you look at MapBox that provide full Map tiles customization as well as markers and overlays that can be used in iOS almost without any effort.